# Advice on good books of geometry for ICPC/IOI

Tags: geometry

Does anyone know any good books on Geometry for icpc preparation? Is there any book which cover most of the geometry topic from beginner to advance level.

Comment: I dk what icpc is. But I recommend Introduction To Geometry by Coxeter.

Comment: ICPC means International Collegiate Programming Contest which is basically solve 11-15 various type of mathematics problem by programming language.